# str.maketrans or re.sub for unicode in Python3

Tags: regex, string, python-3.x, unicode, translate

The desired task is to get `v` to be replaced with their `u` umlaut counterpart.

I could do it as such:

```
>>> replacements = {'v':'u', u'v̄':u'ǖ', u'v́':u'ǘ', u'v̌':u'ǚ', u'v̀':u'ǜ'}
>>> s = u'lv́'
>>> for v, u in replacements.items():
...     s = s.replace(v, u)
... 
>>> s
'lǘ'
```

But when I tried it with `str.maketrans`, it throws a ValueError:

```
>>> str.maketrans({'v':'u', u'v̄':u'ǖ', u'v́':u'ǘ', u'v̌':u'ǚ', u'v̀':u'ǜ'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: string keys in translate table must be of length 1
```

Is it possible to use `str.maketrans` and `str.tranlsate` for the unicode?

If not, what would be the an appropriate single regex substitution to achieved the desired output? Or is it not possible too?

Comment: I don't think `maketrans` is going to work here. I don't think a single regular expression will really work either. (You could make one that calls a function for each replacement, but that seems like an odd solution.) What's wrong with your original code?

Comment: The original code is making 5 operations regardless of whether any form of "v" appears in the original string. I thought `str.maketrans` and `str.translate` would be possible since it would work normally for non-unicode strings.

Comment: I believe `str.maketrans` works fine with unicode, but it only works if the "from" side of the mapping consists of strings of length 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps, though I'm not sure it's more efficient than your original code. (I assume you're after a performance gain?)

```
import re

replacements = {'v': 'u', 'v̀': 'ǜ', 'v̌': 'ǚ', 'v́': 'ǘ', 'v̄': 'ǖ'}
def replace(match):
    return replacements[match.group(0)]

# alternative 1
assert re.sub(r'v̄|v́|v̌|v̀|v', replace, 'lv́vv̌') == 'lǘuǚ'

# alternative 2
assert re.sub(r'v[́̄̌̀]?', replace, 'lv́vv̌') == 'lǘuǚ'
```

Note that in the first alternative, it's important to put the `v` last in the regular expression. Otherwise it will get matched first (rather than the longer sequences).

Comment: Cool! I didn't realize this use of `re.sub` =)